# How to re-enable close button in qt dialog

Tags: qt

I am using `QProgressDialog`and I disable the close (x) button when I start the progress bar.

```
progress->setWindowFlags(progress->windowFlags() & ~Qt::WindowCloseButtonHint);
```

After the operation is complete in `QProcess`, in the finished slot, I am re-enabling the close button but it doesn't work. It instead closes the progress window. I have tried both lines below but it does the same.

```
progress->setWindowFlags(progress->windowFlags() | Qt::WindowCloseButtonHint);
```

or

```
progress->setWindowFlags(progress->windowFlags() | Qt::WindowCloseButtonHint | Qt::CustomizeWindowHint);
```

Why is it not working the way it should?

Comment: Code: `setWindowFlags(windowFlags() & ~Qt::WindowCloseButtonHint);`
`setWindowFlags(windowFlags() | Qt::WindowCloseButtonHint);` is valid and works as expected (Qt5.2)Maybe problem in your connection,slot?

Comment: @Chernobyl it can hardly be connection. I also remove 'cancel' button when `QProgressDialog` starts and show 'Ok' button in the same slot when process finishes via `progress->setCancelButtonText("Ok");`That works fine and the next line to enable the x button back doesn't, it instead closes dialog. I if comment this line, the dialog stays there as expected.

Comment: Oh, I understood and reproduced the problem, really! I will try to figure out.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I figured out problem. You dialog is hidden and there are no way to solve that. You can only `show()` it again.

As [doc](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qwidget.html#windowFlags-prop) said:

> Note: This function calls setParent() when changing the flags for a
>   window, causing the widget to be hidden. You must call show() to make
>   the widget visible again.

From Qt source:

```
void QWidget::setWindowFlags(Qt::WindowFlags flags)
{
    if (data->window_flags == flags)
        return;

    Q_D(QWidget);

    if ((data->window_flags | flags) & Qt::Window) {
        // the old type was a window and/or the new type is a window
        QPoint oldPos = pos();
        bool visible = isVisible();
        setParent(parentWidget(), flags);
        ^^^^^^^^^

        // if both types are windows or neither of them are, we restore
        // the old position
        if (!((data->window_flags ^ flags) & Qt::Window)
            && (visible || testAttribute(Qt::WA_Moved))) {
            move(oldPos);
        }
        // for backward-compatibility we change Qt::WA_QuitOnClose attribute value only when the window was recreated.
        d->adjustQuitOnCloseAttribute();
    } else {
        data->window_flags = flags;
    }
}
```

And as [doc](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qwidget.html#setParent) said again:

> Note: The widget becomes invisible as part of changing its parent,
>   even if it was previously visible. You must call show() to make the
>   widget visible again.

For example:

```
MainWindow w;w.show();
w.setWindowFlags(w.windowFlags() & ~Qt::WindowCloseButtonHint);
w.setWindowFlags(w.windowFlags() | Qt::WindowCloseButtonHint);
w.show();
```

Comment: Wow that was an interesting solution,turn out to be tricky one. thanks!